# JPQL Query Date with interval

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using JPA and JPQL. And I am new in this world;-)
My Query is now giving me data between 2 dates.

```
Query query =em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DTable d JOIN d.history p WHERE (d.vehicle.id = :vehicleId) AND (p.timestamp BETWEEN :curentDate AND :date)");
```

How can I tell JPQL to filter the Data that he is giving me Data between 2 dates but with a time interval of 4 Minutes?.

I hope it is clear.
Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: I mean in the result, between two p.timestamp are at least 4 Minutes difference.

Comment: Could you give an example ? I don't understand what are your datas and what are your expected result.

Comment: This is my result:

Tue Mar 22 17:39:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:37:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:35:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:33:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:31:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:29:52 CET 2011

and I need this :

Tue Mar 22 17:39:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:35:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:31:52 CET 2011
Tue Mar 22 17:27:52 CET 2011

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement: the difference between two supplied dates should be **at least** four minutes. According to JPA 1.0 specification, comparison expression between dates must follow this pattern

> datetime_expression **comparison_operator** datetime_expression

Where comparison_operator can be =, >, >=, <, <=, <>. What you can do is

Take the difference between your supplied dates as follows

```
Timestamp dateA ...
Timestamp dateB ...

Timestamp difference = new Timestamp(Math.abs(dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime()));
```

And create a [Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which represents 4 minutes

```
Timestamp fourMinutes = new Timestamp(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0);
```

Now your query **should looks like**

```
where :difference >= :fourMinutes
```

Comment: Thanks it helps but I don't know the 
Timestamp dateA
Timestamp dateB in the query I am asking for data and this data should be between date c and Today and I only needs the data with 4 Minutes interval in the date. Sorry my question was not clear.